# mgf of MultiNormal find conditional distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory

## Problem

Let 
We have that $  {X}= (X_1,X_2,X_3)^T$ where
$X$ has mgf $$
 \psi_{X_1,X_2,X_3} = \exp\{2t_1 - t_3 + t^2 _1 + 2t^2 _2 + 3t_3 ^2 - 2t_1 t_3 \}
$$

Now we define  $ {Y} = (X_1+X_3,X_1 +X_2)^T$ and we want to deteremine the distribution of $Y_1 \mid Y_2 = 1$.

From Gut An intermediate course in probability ch5q30.

## Attempt

IF $ {X} \in  {N}( {\mu}, {\Lambda})$ we would have that
$$
\psi_{ {X}}( {t})=\exp\{ {t}^T {\mu} + \frac{1}{2} {t}^T {\Lambda} {t}\}
$$
hence we want to show that 
$$ 
 {t}^T {\mu} + \frac{1}{2} {t}^T {\Lambda} {t} = 2t_1 - t_3 + t^2 _1 + 2t^2 _2 + 3t_3 ^2 - 2t_1 t_3
$$
for some non negative definite matrix $ {\Lambda}$ and vector $ {\mu}$ Putting
$$
 {\Lambda}=
\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 0 & -2   \\  0 & 4 & 0 \\ -2 & 0 & 6 \end{pmatrix}
\text{ and }
 {\mu}=
\begin{pmatrix} 2   \\  0 \\ -1\end{pmatrix}
$$
We get that
$$ 
 {t}^T {\mu} + \frac{1}{2} {t}^T {\Lambda} {t} = 2t_1 -t_3 + t^2 _1 + 2t^2 _2 + 3t_3 ^2 - 2t_1 t_3
$$
Now we define  $ {Y} = (X_1+X_3,X_1 +X_2)^T$ and we want to deteremine the distribution of $Y_1 \mid Y_2 = 1$. We know from standard theory that $ {Y} \in  {N}( {\mu_Y}, {\Lambda_Y})$
where
$$
 {\Lambda_Y}=
\begin{pmatrix} 4 & 0   \\  0 & 6 \end{pmatrix}
\text{ and }
 {\mu_Y}=
\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 2  \end{pmatrix}
$$
hence $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ are independent and $Y_1 \mid Y_2 = 1 = Y_1 \in N(1,4)$.

## My Question

This is wrong according to my book. it says N(4/5,18/5).

Answer (score 0):

$$s_1Y_1+s_2Y_2=(s_1+s_2)X_1+s_2X_2+s_1X_3\implies\psi_Y(s_1,s_2)=\psi_X(s_1+s_2,s_2,s_1)$$